# Change reply-to header of 'new order' email in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-headers, email-notifications

We were able to modify the reply-to email for the 'new order' email that WooCommerce generates to the admin email of the site using the filter from this answer:

[Custom "reply to" email header in Woocommerce New Order email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171568/custom-reply-to-email-header-in-woocommerce-new-order-email-notification/49172231#49172231)

What we're hoping to do, however, is set the reply-to email to the recipient address that we've listed for the 'new order' email in WooCommerce > Settings > Emails.

We're also open to hardcoding the email we need the reply-to to go to into the above filter.

Would anyone be able to offer guidance as to how to do this? I'm a bit stuck. I don't understand what can be put into `get_option( )` well enough to know how this can be successfully modified.

Comment: Sorry, @LoicTheAztec! I wasn't aware that was the way to do it. I'll update now.

Comment: Is better to give the link in the question (always *as you credit the author*). Now if you make changes on the code, you should add the code in the question (giving the link of the source inspirational code). If the code comes from outside StackOverFlow threads, It's recommended to add it in your question.

Comment: Got it. That makes complete sense. Thanks, @LoicTheAztec!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this question, you want to add the recipient address that is set for 'new order' email as a reply-to email address. Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'new_order_reply_to_admin_header', 20, 3 );
function new_order_reply_to_admin_header( $header, $email_id, $order ) {

    if ( $email_id === 'new_order' ){
        $email = new WC_Email($email_id);

        $header = "Content-Type: " . $email->get_content_type() . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Reply-to: ' . $email->get_recipient() . "\r\n";
    }
    return $header;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.