# Change "reply to" email address in all Woocommerce emails notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I would like to change the email address that should always be used as the **reply address** for all emails notifications.

How is this possible with Woocommerce?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Updates:

- Added utf8_decode() to handle special characters (still works in WooCommerce 8.6.1)
- Since WooCommerce 3.7, the `WC_Email` instance object is now included as the 4th argument in the function.

The following will change the "Reply to" email address (and name) in all email notifications:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'change_reply_to_email_address', 10, 4 );
function change_reply_to_email_address( $header, $email_id, $order, $email ) {

    // HERE below set the name and the email address
    $reply_to_name  = 'Jack Smith';
    $reply_to_email = 'jack.smith@doamin.tld';

    $header  = 'Content-Type: ' . $email->get_content_type() . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'Reply-to: ' . utf8_decode($reply_to_name) . ' <' . sanitize_email($reply_to_email) . ">\r\n";

    return $header;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works *(Thanks to **helgatheviking**)*.

Related: [Custom "reply to" email header in Woocommerce New Order email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171568/custom-reply-to-email-header-in-woocommerce-new-order-email-notification/49172231#49172231)

Comment: The `$email` object can be passed as the 4th parameter to `woocommerce_email_headers`

Comment: @helgatheviking I dont see it yet in the docs: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#394 …  but in Github yes: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php … So this is a new improvement [committed on 14 Aug 2019](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/d88fdb6adf34f478aa722ac19f123242c728bbf5)… I have added this information in the answer.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the above code shows: Reply-To: Jack Smith <Jack Smith> on WooCommerce version:3.8.0 & WordPress version: 5.3. Please guide me.

Comment: @KoolPal You need to replace the two variables $reply_to_name and $reply_to_email with your info.

Comment: I have the (updated) code in my functions.php. Today it stopped working, and I cannot think of any reason why. How can I debug this please? I do have another snippet for adding a CC to all emails and that one is still working fine. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have tested the code with WooCommerce 8.6.1 and it still work.