# Change “reply to” email header in Woocommerce for New Order and shipped email notifications

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I am trying to add a filter to change my New Order and Shipped emails reply-to addresses for customers only. I tried using this solution [Change "reply to" email address in all Woocommerce emails notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240846/change-reply-to-email-address-in-all-woocommerce-emails-notifications). It works for the customer but now the store owner email doesn't get any New order email. I suppose that the store owner email is not getting the New Order emails because its the same reply-to address. Is there a way to change the reply-to only for the customer's New Order and Shipped emails?

Please help!

Comment: Why does the reply to email need to be different from the sender's email?

Comment: Because I wont be using that email.

Comment: But why not put your email as the "from" email and avoid the need to code something at all?

Comment: @helgatheviking - because when using phpmail (the default), it is spoofing the from address and gets rejected for DMARC reasons if you happen to make the from address be a yahoo address. Also, if you want to set up an SMTP address to use as a mailbot for your whole wordpress site that is a noreply address, it is nice to have a separate reply-to at an address that is attended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should prevent adding the reply to email header if it's the same as the recipient:

```
/**
 * Change reply to email address for customer emails.
 *
 * @param  array $header - The email headers.
 * @param  string $email_id
 * @param  object $order WC_Order
 * @param  object $email - The WC_Email class object for this particular email.
 * @return array
 */
function change_reply_to_email_address( $header, $email_id, $order, $email ) {

    // HERE below set the name and the email address
    $reply_to_name  = 'Jack Smith';
    $reply_to_email = 'jack.smith@doamin.tld';

    // Set the reply to email only if it's not one of the recipients.
    if( false !== strpos( $reply_to_email, $email->get_recipient() ) ) {
        $header  = "Content-Type: " . $email->get_content_type() . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Reply-to: ' . $reply_to_name . ' <' . $reply_to_email . ">\r\n";
    }

    return $header;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'change_reply_to_email_address', 10, 4 );
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to check if the email is an admin email or not, so alternatively you could conditionally check for specific email IDs.

Comment: Hello, I added the code but can't figure out the "if" part. I didn't do any changes to that part and only receive a successful email to my admin email but didn't got anything in the customers email. hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm... I think you are right and the conditional IF logic looks off. I made an edit, but unfortunately can't really test it right now. If this still doesn't work, you could use something like `in_array( $email_id, array( 'new_order', 'customer_completed_order' ) )` where the array holds all the IDs of the customer emails.

Comment: Great! If it works, would you mind accepting this as the answer.